# How to make Recursive Query in sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I need to calculate the value of indebtedness column so that when `openingBalance !=0 then indebtedness = openingBalnce+SalesTotal-SalesReturn`. But, when `openingBalnce = 0` then indebtedness = indebtedness of the previous monthSales with the same SalesID. If the previous value = 0 get the previous value and continue get previous value till have value in this column:

```html
 SalesMonth SalesID  openingBalance  SalesTotal SalesReturn  Indebtednes
    ---------- -------  --------------  ---------- -----------  ------------  
    1           1             352200     0          5600            Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           2             50000     1100         0              Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           3             9500      6000         0              Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           1              0         0          1200            Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           2              0         300          0             Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           3              0         500        1000            Null
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           1              0         600         0              NULL
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           2              0         200         0              NULL
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           3              0         0           10             NULL
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .
    .
    .
    12           1             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           2             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           3             0          0           0              NULL
```

And Output like this:

```
    when openingBalance !=0 then Indebtednes=openingBalnce+SalesTotal-SalesReturn

    when openingBalnce =0 then Indebtednes=Indebtednes (of the previous
    month of the same SalesID)+SalesTotal-SalesReturn.
```

And this is the output i want.

```html
 SalesMonth SalesID  openingBalance  SalesTotal SalesReturn  Indebtednes
    ---------- -------  --------------  ---------- -----------  ------------  
    1           1             352200     0          5600            346600
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           2             50000     1100         0              51100
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           3             9500      6000         0              15500
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           1              0         0          1200            345400
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           2              0         300          0             51400
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           3              0         500        1000            15000
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           1              0         600         0              346000
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           2              0         200         0              51600
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           3              0         0           10             14990
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .
    .
    .
    12           1             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           2             0          0           0              NULL
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    12           3             0          0           0              NULL
```

Comment: Any help to this problem please

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below cte query

```
declare @tb table(SalesMonth int,SalesID int,
openingBalance money,SalesTotal money,SalesReturn money,Indebtednes money)
insert into @tb(SalesMonth,SalesID,openingBalance,SalesTotal,SalesReturn,Indebtednes) 
values  (1,1,352200,0,5600,Null)
        ,(1,2,50000,1100,0,Null)
        ,(1,3,9500,6000,0,Null)
        ,(2,1,0,0,1200,Null)
        ,(2,2,0,300,0,Null)
        ,(2,3,0,500,1000,Null)
        ,(3,1,0,600,0,NULL)
        ,(3,2,0,200,0,NULL)
        ,(3,3,0,0,10,NULL)


    ;with t1 as (select *, row_number() over 
    (order by salesid,SalesMonth) as rno from @tb),
    t2(inde,rno,salid,mnth)as 
    (select case  when openingBalance !=0 then 
    openingBalance+SalesTotal-SalesReturn
    when openingBalance =0 then  0 end as inde, 
    rno,SalesID,SalesMonth from t1 where rno=1
    union all 
    select case  when openingBalance !=0 then 
    openingBalance+SalesTotal-SalesReturn
    when openingBalance =0 then 
    case when SalesID=salid then inde+SalesTotal-SalesReturn 
    else 0 end end,
    t1.rno,t1.SalesID,SalesMonth from t2 join t1 on t2.rno+1=t1.rno     )
    select SalesMonth,SalesID,openingBalance,
    SalesTotal,SalesReturn,inde as Indebtednes from t1 
    inner join t2 on t1.SalesID=t2.salid and 
    t1.SalesMonth=t2.mnth order by mnth,salid
```